# How to flash libgdx label

Tags: java, libgdx

I managed to make a label containing the string: "Tap anywhere to continue" and have it added to a table. However, as of now it is static and I would like to have it constantly flashing. Are there any methods that can allow me to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Make Actor that contains Label, add that Actor into stage. Add forever scale up-down action on that Actor.